# Proper approach to debug PC startup problems (POST)

Tags: cpu, motherboard

My CPU was heating up to around 65 deg C and last time this had happened (about a year ago), I got thermal paste put between the CPU and heat sink and this managed to get it down to about 45 - 50 degrees.

This time, I got some thermal paste and put it myself.
However, my PC is not showing the POST display and not starting up.

**This is what happens**

- LEDs light up
- HDDs spin
- Mouse is getting power
- All fans including the processor fan starts
- **No** display on monitor
- **No** diagnostic beep sounds (no sounds at all)

**What I have tried**

- Removing everything including RAM, HDD, PCI cards, AGP card
- Boot up machine

*No changes from first state.*

***What steps can I take to figure out where the problem lies?***

**Note**
(might be important)
When I removed the heat sink, the processor came out with it (it was stuck to it inspite of the processor latch on)
Had to pry it separate with a screw-driver.

**Configuration**

- Pentium 4, 2.8 Ghz with HT (very old, I know)
- Original Intel Mobo with onboard sound and graphics (GB series)
- 2x512 Mb DDR-RAM
- 2 SATA disks (320 Gigs / 250 gigs)
- DVD Writer
- Creative Sound Card
- Network card

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you were rough on your processor by using a screwdriver to pry the heatsink loose, the first thing I would do to troubleshoot would be to try a different processor.  If you've made no other changes, the processor is by far the most likely thing to be broken given your description.

You should also check to make sure you haven't left any cords unplugged.

Note that 65 C is not typically a bad temperature for your CPU to be at.  Most CPUs can handle up to 80~100 without any problems.